# Get Updated Value in MySQL instead of affected rows

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to find an answer to this question, but haven't found any definitive "yes" or "no" in all my research.

I'm running a simple MySQL query like this:

```
 UPDATE item SET `score`=`score`+1 WHERE `id`=1
```

Is there a way for that query to return the updated value, instead of the number of rows affected?  Just as a reference, I'm doing this in PHP, so the actual code looks like:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE item SET `score`=`score`+1 WHERE `id`=1";
 $new_value = mysql_query($sql); 
 //Unfortunately this does not return the new value
```

I know I could do a second query and just SELECT the value, but I'm trying to cut down on queries as much as possible.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it with a stored procedure that updates, and then selects the new value into an output parameter.
The following returns one column `new_score` with the new value.

```sql
DELIMITER $$   -- Change DELIMITER in order to use ; withn the procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE increment_score
(
   IN id_in INT
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE item SET score = score + 1 WHERE id = id_in;
    SELECT score AS new_score FROM item WHERE id = id_in;
END
$$            -- Finish CREATE PROCEDURE statement
DELIMITER ;   -- Reset DELIMITER to standard ;
```

In PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL increment_score($id)");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['new_score'];
```

Comment: Is the performance of doing this in a stored procedure any better than just doing two SQL queries?

Comment: @jwegner Performance will probably be a little bit better because the RDBMS doesn't have to parse either of the queries.  Both are already compiled in the procedure on the RDBMS' side.

Comment: Is there a reason why `id` is compare to `id_in` in the `UPDATE` query and `in_id` in the `SELECT` query?

Comment: @jwegner, then it appears to me that you accidentally reversed "in" and "id" in the variable declaration and the first query.

Comment: @Keyslinger I see what you mean - just a typo, fixed.

Comment: I strongly believe that the performance gain of this over two queries is negligible. Especially with queries as simple as these.

Comment: @taylorcressy I would agree too, for basic usage. That old comment should read more like _"On a massive scale, performance will probably be a little bit better..."_. At a normal, small webapp scale, there will probably be no measurable benefit.

Answer (score 12):

No, there's nothing like postgresql's [UPDATE ... RETURNING output_expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-update.html) in MySQL (yet?).

Comment: Doesn't really help with the question (if there is actually an answer), but +1 for an interesting piece of info!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to run another Query SELECT then here is another way to do it. I have modified Mr. Berkowski code for reference:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE increment_score
(
   IN id_in INT
)
BEGIN
    set @newScore := null;
    UPDATE item SET score = IF((@newScore := score+1) <> NULL IS NULL, @newScore, NULL) WHERE id = id_in;
    SELECT @newScore;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cant. You could make a function or stored procedure that could do the insert and return the updated value but that would still require you to execute two queries from within the function or stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a trigger, and you will know everything about the modifications.