# SQL Update And Select In A Single Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is there a way in SQL (MySQL) to increment a value, and also return the value in a single query. I am trying to ovoid doing two queries like the following:

QUERY 1

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_col = (my_col + 1) WHERE something = something_else;
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT my_col FROM my_table WHERE something = something_else;
```

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you want to do two queries?

Comment: why you want to do this?,you can calculate it from the php side

Comment: Trying to eek everything out of performance.

Comment: You will have to use stored procedure, check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7446154/1588182

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL UPDATE and SELECT in one pass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562693/mysql-update-and-select-in-one-pass)

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is still no such possibility in MySQL, but take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817414/output-clause-in-mysql) for a possible workaround that at least lets you have the select and update work with the same data transactionally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a select and a update at the same time.
If you want to avoid the select you can declare a variable and put there the value, but that will put the last updated row value in the variable.

```
declare @value int

UPDATE my_table SET my_col = (my_col + 1), @value = (my_col + 1) WHERE something = something_else;
```

Comment: but then how are they returning the @value? a select would still need to be performed

Comment: @bluefeet like I said, this only avoid to select data from the table again. He would have to make the select of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what scripting language you are using but here is an example on creating a stored procedure in MySQL that returns the updated value so you can update and select in one operation:

[Get Updated Value in MySQL instead of affected rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446073/get-updated-value-in-mysql)