# MySQL select and update table at same time

Tags: java, mysql

I want to select a value one by one from my MySQL table and using this value get some value from different table. After getting the value I want to update my same table with this value.
Can I select and update the table **at the same time**?

I want to use Java to loop the table selecting values one by one from table.

Comment: So, what you have tried?

Comment: i didn't tried this yet. I just want to know can this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Update And Select In A Single Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849916/sql-update-and-select-in-a-single-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set statement to be updatable. Then you can use the setters of the resultset to update any value.

You can also probably solve this in a single sql query but i'll have to see the tables to create an example.

Like this for instance:

```
update table_a a
set column_name=(select b.new_column_value from table_b b where b.uid=a.uid)
```

You can also add a where clause to the update to only perform it on some records in table_a

Comment: How it can be solved in a single query. Beacause first i need a value from different table to update the table.

Comment: Can i also join two tables in this sub-query?

Comment: Yes, the sub query can be built as an ordinary select