# mysql update column then select updated value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

**tbl_user**

```
id
user_id
amount
```

first i want to update a row based on id

```
$amount = 123; // dyanamic value
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_user SET amount=amount-'$amount' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1 ";
```

now i want to get updated value of amount column i have applied this sql

```
$sql = "SELECT amount FROM tbl_user  WHERE id='$id'  LIMIT 1 ";
```

my question is can i combine both of above sql or any single query to achieve above task?

Comment: Do you want to in mysql or have you use any front end framework?

Comment: @Sadikhasan I want only sql query

Comment: What you want to do in single query?

Comment: both update and select. first update the column with decrement some dynamic value then select the new value

Comment: I think it is not possible in single query.

Comment: Using variables inside your SQL query most likely is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Consider [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The best you could imitate is to use two lines of queries, probably using a variable like:

```
 UPDATE tbl_user SET
     amount = @amount := amount-'$amount'
 WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1;

 SELECT @amount;
```

The best you could do then is to create a `Stored Procedure` like:

```
 DELIMITER //

 CREATE PROCEDURE `return_amount` ()
 BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_user SET
     amount = @amount := amount-'$amount'
    WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1;

    SELECT @amount;
 END //
```

And then [call `Stored Procedure`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures/) in your `PHP`.

Note: `PostgreSQL` has this kind of option using `RETURNING` statement that would look like this:

```
 UPDATE tbl_user SET amount=amount-'$amount' 
 WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1
 RETURNING amount
```

See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html)

Comment: I bench the 1st solution (UPDATE with @var and SELECT @var) and it is only 2-5% faster than doing 2 requests like exposed in the question. So I am not sure it is good to use such improvement because your SQL become non-standard...

Comment: @fred727 So, how do you propose an improvement based on OP's exact requirements, namely, combining two lines of queries into one?

Comment: you can use like this :

UPDATE TABLE SET columnname = columnname + 1;   select columnname from TABLE

Comment: Will the single query approach handles simultaneous updates from different processes without any side effect?

Comment: This is probably the worst solution of the list. Not only is it doing another select, granted not using a table but still needs processing, like the other proposed solutions, the data may not reflect whats actually in the database due to triggers. This solution will fail if there is or the DBA decides to add a trigger later on that modifies the field on update. It also assumes that the where clause is a unique field, which you are only going to get the last updated value.

Answer (score 9):

A function can do this easily. It sounds like you want to limit how many times your code connects to the database. With a stored function or procedure, you are only making one connection. Yes, the stored function has two queries inside it (update then select), but these are executed on the server side without stopping to do round trips to the client.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e6a09/1/0

Here's my skeleton of your table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_user (
  id       VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id  VARCHAR(100),
  amount   DECIMAL(17,4) );

INSERT INTO tbl_user VALUES ('1', 'John', '100.00');
```

And the proposed function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION incrementAmount
  (p_id VARCHAR(100), p_amount DECIMAL(17,4))
RETURNS DECIMAL(17,4)
BEGIN
  UPDATE tbl_user
SET amount = amount + p_amount
WHERE id = p_id;
  RETURN (SELECT amount FROM tbl_user WHERE id = p_id);
END
//
```

Then you just run one query, a `SELECT` on the function you just created:

```
SELECT incrementAmount('1', 5.00)
```

The query result is:

```
105
```

Comment: Realized after I posted this that almost the same question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7446154/1680777

Comment: "Function" works to me. "Procedure" not works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with a single query, but you can combine multiple commands into a script and execute them with a single request to the database server.

Run this script:

```
"UPDATE tbl_user SET amount=amount-'$amount' WHERE id='".$id."';SELECT amount FROM tbl_user  WHERE id='".$id."'; "
```

Also, you might want to check whether $id is a number, as I do not see a protection against SQL injection inside your code. SQL injection is a serious threat, you would do better to prepare and protect yourself against it.

Comment: can we use procedure?

Comment: Of course you can. If you want to do so, then create the procedure which expects a value for id and put the script inside the procedure.

Comment: is procedure takes much higher execution time than a sql?

Comment: No, it does not. In fact if you need to use it in multiple places then a procedure is advisable.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use:

```
UPDATE  tbl_user  SET id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id),  amount = 2.4,user_id=4 WHERE id = 123;

// SELECT
$id =SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT amount,user_id FROM tbl_user  WHERE id = $id   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is probably the closest answer, however this still has an atomic problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here would be the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateAndSelect
(
    @amount MONEY,
    @id INT
)
AS
BEGIN

   UPDATE tbl_user
   SET amount = @amount
   WHERE id = @id
   LIMIT 1

   SELECT amount
   FROM tbl_user
   WHERE id = @id
   LIMIT 1

END
GO
```

You would call this stored procedure by setting your variables (@amoutn and @id) and then calling:

```
exec UpdateAndSelect
```

Hope this helps solve your problem

Comment: I don't think that is valid syntax for MySQL. Looks like T-SQL to me (for Microsoft SQL Server).

Comment: Oh actually, that is T-SQL, my mistake