# How to get variable from updating query in TypedQuery?

Tags: java, sql

I have typed query

```
UPDATE data SET data.numberOfSentMessages = data.numberOfSentMessages +1 WHERE data.id = :id
```

I need to know what is numberOfSentMessages after update. How can I get it?

Comment: What about a new query after the Update `SELECT d.numberOfSentMessages  FROM data d WHERE d.id = :id`

Comment: I would like to have everything from one query

Comment: Can't you create a stored procedure, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691576/mysql-update-column-then-select-updated-value

Comment: It is what I wanted, thank you!