# MySQL- Select and Update at the same time

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM outbox where Status=0 ;
```

then I need to update the selected records so Status should be equal 1

i.e (`UPDATE outbox(selected records from SELECT query) SET Status =1` )

any help ?

Comment: Why do you need to select first?

Comment: Do you have any id column for the table?

Comment: Do you mean you want to update and immediately fetch all updated records?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446073/get-updated-value-in-mysql-instead-of-affected-rows). I guess you are asking the same.

Answer (score 3):

This is a much harder problem than it sounds.  Yes, in the simplistic case where you are only thinking of one user and a few records, it seems easy.  But, databases are designed to be ACID-compliant, with multiple users and multiple concurrent transactions that can all be affecting the data at the same time.  And there is no single statement in MySQL that does what you want (other databases support an `OUTPUT` clause, `RETURNING` or something similar).

One structure that will work in MySQL is to place the items in a temporary table, then do the update, then return them.  The following shows the semantics using transactions:

```
start transaction;

create temporary table TempOutboxStatus0 as
    select *
    from outbox
    where status = 0;

update outbox o
    set status = 1
    where status = 0;

select *
from TempOutboxStatus0;

commit;
```

For the `update`, I actually prefer:

```
    where exists (select 1 from TempOutboxStatus0 t where t.outboxid = o.outboxid);
```

because its intention is clearer -- and the code is safer in case the conditions subtly change.

Note:  you may want to use explicit table locks.  Such considerations depend on the storage engine you are using.

Comment: What's to prevent `outbox` being updated between the `create temporary table` and `update` commands?  Surely one should use a locking read, e.g. `SELECT * FROM outbox WHERE status=0 FOR UDPATE` (and so doing avoids the need for a temporary table)?

Comment: @eggyal . . . Nothing.  However, the transaction *should* ensure ACID-compliance -- although this might not always be true in MySQL.  My concern isn't updates during the `select`.  It is updates between the `select` and the `update`.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN
        Start transaction;
        SELECT * 
            FROM 
                outbox 
            where 
                Status = 0 and
                Is_Expired = 0 and
                Service_ID=p_service_id
        order by    
                Next_Try_Date asc FOR Update;          

        update outbox 
            set 
                Status=1 
            where
                Status = 0 and
                Is_Expired = 0 and
                Service_ID=p_service_id;
        commit;

END
```

is this possible .. it seems it works with me

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, the outbox is your table:

```
update outbox set Status = 1 where Status = 0
```

Comment: I need the result set from select query to use it in my application then I need to update this result set !! FYI this code is part of stored procedure

Comment: What is query? table?

Comment: @IslamMuntasser but the result set from the first query is every row with `Status = 0`?!

Comment: the query 
Select * from outbox where Status= 0 ; (this will be the result set) then i need to update this result set so Status will be "1" so how can I update and select in the same query !!

Comment: I know that I can select to temp table then update the main table by the IDs of the temp table .. but it headache ..

Comment: @IslamMuntasser: You can't "update and select in the same query".  But doing so is rarely necessary: that you're trying to do it probably indicates poor design decisions have been made along the way.  @Strawberry asked above for more information on why you're attempting it, the answer to which would help us to suggest a better design.  However, as things stand and since "this code is part of stored procedure", you could simply perform the `SELECT` first and then perform the `UPDATE` afterwards: the sproc will output the resultset from the `SELECT` and then update the table's contents.

Comment: Ok .. the first part is good .. the sproc will return the resultset from the SELECT.. Then I need to Update the selected IDs from the select query where Status of them = 0 to be 1

Comment: @IslamMuntasser: So what's wrong with running the `update` command as given in Roy's answer above?  The set of records that it will update should be the same as the set that were previously selected, unless you have concurrent connections that may have changed the data in the interim.  If concurrency is your concern, then you will either need to use a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) within a transaction (if your table uses a transactional storage engine such as InnoDB), or else explicitly [lock the table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/lock-tables.html).

Comment: No you don't. You just need the query @RoyShmuli has given you.

Comment: @Strawberry: How then would you handle a concurrent connection altering the data between the select and the update?

Answer (score -3):

you can do it like below

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM outbox where `Status`=0");
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$update="UPDATE `outbox` SET `Status` =1 where 
'your column name'='your previous fetched value');
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP is using this language?

Comment: i have just seen the mysql query so i thought so

Comment: I wrote MYSQL stored procedure .. but I don't know what this language is ?

Comment: i have written this in mysql and php . you can use it in your way i am just describing the logic nothing else

Comment: Unless bound up within a transaction, this is a terrible idea. It's also unnecessary.

Comment: So much rudeness it's sad.