# Is there a way to update a table, and select it within one statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-injection, code-injection

I am currently practicing SQL injection on a local host web application. In order to successfully do that, a value must be returned in the statement (by using `SELECT`). I'm trying to change the password of the user:

```
changepwd', (UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('new password') 
             WHERE user='root' UNION SELECT authentication_string from mysql.user)) #
```

With SQL injection you can't use `;`. I tried `UNION`in that example to see if it would work but no luck. Any other ideas i could try?

Comment: This is very easy with Postgres. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446073/get-updated-value-in-mysql-instead-of-affected-rows).

In short the answer is create a stored procedure.

Comment: generally speaking this is the way to go, but he's asking about sql injection, so creating a SP is not an option

Comment: Then is it possible to inject and procedure and call it? Maybe by changing the delimiter and running several calls. (I don't know if it's possible and haven't tested it)